# Accepting new line character in POST request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, post

I am getting a JSON from a third party as a POST request that I currently mapping to my object in Spring Boot. This call fails when any attribute has a newline character because it's not escaped. How do I accept this JSON on my end.
Example:

```
{
"name":"xyz",
"age":32,
"comment": "Hello, this is 
an example comment of how I am getting the JSON"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This call fails when any attribute has a newline character because it's not escaped.

It *should* fail - unescaped newline characters are not permitted in [JSON strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7).  If the HTTP request has

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Then what you have here is a malformed request, and the server should be returning [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), rather than trying to fix the document.

```
cat <<JSON | jq .
{
"name":"xyz",
"age":32,
"comment": "Hello, this is
an example comment of how I am getting the JSON"
}
JSON
```

```
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 5, column 48
```

---

```
cat <<JSON | jq -r .comment
{
"name":"xyz",
"age":32,
"comment": "Hello, this is \nan example comment of how I am getting the JSON"
}
JSON
```

```
Hello, this is 
an example comment of how I am getting the JSON
```

Comment: That's true but third party software would need fixing but in the mean time, I need to be able to process those values